# How to map parent class values to child class in spring boot java

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a Parent.class, which has 3 fields. And I have a Child.class, which has only one field and it requires the Parent class fields. So this is the following design implmentation I did.

```
class Parent {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String surname;
}
```

```
class Child extends Parent{
    String childField;
}
```

I am fetching the parent class fields from the external source, with the **type as Parent**. So now I wanted to map these fields to **Child**. I have tried the type casting as following:

```
Parent parent = fetchAndSetTheDetails(); // Method which will give the parent details
Child childInstance = (Child) parent;
```

I dont want to explict set the every field from parent to child instance. In future I might increase the fields in parent. So I dont want to set each field explicitly like following:

```
Child childInstance = new Child();
childInstance.setFirstName(parent.getFistName());
childInstance.setLastName(parent.getLastName());
childInstance.setSurname(parent.getSurname());
```

Is there any way that I can map in one go instead of explicitly setting them?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: *class Child implements Parent* doesn't compile, because you only can `implement` Interfaces not classes. You can only `extend` classes

Comment: You need to do that manually. You cannot cast an instance of `Parent` to `Child`, because that instance simply is not a child. Create a factory method like `Child c = Child.fromParent(parent)` and set the values there.

Comment: The only Idea I have is using reflection.

Comment: But where do you know that it is class`Child` not an other subclass of `Parent`

Answer (score 0):

you can use mapper class with the help of this class you can do this thing
below is link you can read it
https://reflectoring.io/autotmatic-refactoring-safe-java-mapping/